# Sprite velocity/speed is varies on different devices

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am using the code below to move my sprite from one position to another.

```
let screenScale: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

var travelSpeed: CGFloat = 20*screenScale
let displacement = CGVector(dx: destination.x-enemy!.sprite.position.x, dy: destination.y-enemy!.sprite.position.y)
let radius = sqrt(displacement.dx*displacement.dx+displacement.dy*displacement.dy)
let normal = CGVector(dx: displacement.dx/radius, dy: displacement.dy/radius)
let impulse = CGVector(dx: normal.dx*travelSpeed, dy: normal.dy*travelSpeed)
let relativeVelocity = CGVector(dx:impulse.dx-enemy!.sprite.physicsBody!.velocity.dx, dy:impulse.dy-enemy!.sprite.physicsBody!.velocity.dy);

enemy!.sprite.physicsBody!.velocity=CGVectorMake(enemy!.sprite.physicsBody!.velocity.dx+relativeVelocity.dx*rate, enemy!.sprite.physicsBody!.velocity.dy+relativeVelocity.dy*rate);
```

But when I tested it on my iPhone 6S Plus the sprite moved considerably faster than on my iPhone 5. I thought the line below caters for the different dimensions, since I am using the screen scale:

```
var travelSpeed: CGFloat = 20*screenScale
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: of course,  you are saying for 6+ to move at 60, and 5 to move at 40,  why are you doing this?

Comment: `scale` is the factor between logical coordinates (points) and device pixels, and can be 1, 2, or 3. It does *not* describe the dimension of the screen.

Comment: okay. When I use a constant for the travelSpeed the 5 is a lot faster than the 6+. How can I get them to move at the same speed?

Comment: What is the scene's scale mode?

Comment: @Kendel The scale mode is `SKSceneScaleMode`

Comment: Could you specify which case? SKSceneScaleMode is not the scale mode... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SKSceneScaleMode

Comment: @Kendel Sorry, the `SKSceneScaleMode` is 0 which is `Fill`

Comment: If it is fill,  the objects are moving at the same speed,  you are just zoomed in on bigger devices

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I created 3x images for the 6S+ to give the same look

Comment: that means nothing,  all 3x means is that for every point, there are 3x3 pixels,  you work in points, it is very rare that you work in pixels in iOS

Comment: @Knight0fDragon but though the objects are moving at the same speed the seeming difference is too great and very noticeable.

Comment: are you using GameScene(size:view.frame.size)  if so, stop right now

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I am using a custom `GameScene(size: self.size, levelName:.level2)`

Comment: what is self.size. the size of your view?  that is your problem

Comment: Your game scene should be a static size,  if you want the size to be that of your view,  use the `.ResizeFill` scale mode.  This allows you versatility when you decide to change your mind on things in the future

Comment: Okay, I changed my GameScene to `GameScene( levelName:.level2)` and removed super.init(size: size). Now I get a `Use of 'self' in method call 'methodName' before super.init initialises self` error at every method call in `GameScene`. Is there another way round my issue?

Comment: yes, make sure you call super before you call self, like the error is telling you not to do

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I am having the same issue. I removed the size parameters from my `SKScene` initializers. For example, for my `PosterScene` `SKScene`, it begins like `class PosterScene: SKScene {
    override init(){
        super.init()
`  but I get the error `fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(size:)' for class 'SuperGame.PosterScene'`

Comment: @iGetIt sounds to me like you are using filenamed as your init?  Am I right?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon No, I am not using fileNamed parameter for my init

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I removed the size parameters from all my `SKScene`s

Comment: @iGetIt then I can't help you out with out knowing more context,  init(size:) is the only init exclusively for SKSceneNode, (The rest come from parents)  I will need to see more code to help you out.  Make a new question and reference this question in it so that you do not get downvoted

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I just posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494876/fatal-error-use-of-unimplemented-initializer-initsize-for-class

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I don't think I fully understand how `self.size` could be causing the speed variations on different devices

Comment: @igetit, if you run 10 miles an hour, how long will it take you to run 10 miles?  How long will it take you to run 15 miles?  The iphone 5 is 10 miles long, the iphone 6+ is 15 miles long, it will take you 1 hour to go across iphone 5, and 1.5 hours to go across the 6+.  If you want to get across the iphone 6+ in 1 hour, you need to make your speed 15 miles per hour