# fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(size:)' for class

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I was testing my app on different devices and realized the sprite movements were quite inconsistent (running considerably faster on some devices as compared to others). I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234362/sprite-velocity-speed-is-varies-on-different-devices?noredirect=1#comment68232853_39234362) and followed the instructions and removed the size parameters from all my `SKScene`s then I got the error:

```
fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(size:)' for class 'SuperGame.PosterScene'
```

Please see my `PosterScene` class below and the `GameViewController` class in which it is called.

PosterScene

```
class PosterScene: SKScene {

 override init(){
    super.init()

    let posterImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "poster")
    posterImage.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    self.addChild(posterImage)

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([  SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0), SKAction.run({ self.changeToMainMenuScene() }) ])

    self.run(sequence)

}

func changeToMainMenuScene  ()  {

    let mainMenuScene = MainMenuScene()
    self.view!.presentScene(mainMenuScene)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

GameViewController:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    let skView = self.view as? SKView

    if skView?.scene == nil  {
        skView?.showsFPS = true
        skView?.showsNodeCount = true
        skView?.showsPhysics = true
        skView?.ignoresSiblingOrder = false

        //starting the game with the Poster Scene
        let posterScene = PosterScene()
        posterScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        skView?.presentScene(posterScene)
    }

}

override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
    return true
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}
}
```

Comment: You should be overriding `init(size:)`, not `init()`

Comment: @dan I was originally using `init(size:)` which wasn't giving any errors but the sprite speeds varied on different devices. In an attempt to solve the varying sprite speeds issue I removed the size parameter as recommended in the linked question.

Comment: @iGetIt, now that I can see this in code, you are misunderstanding me,  I did not say to not use `size:`  I said not to use `size:view.frame.size`.  If you must work 100% in code (I do not recommend this, separating design and functionality makes life 1000 times easier)  Then you should be picking a static size, not a size based on the view, because the goal is to scale across all devices so that it looks the same.

Answer (score 3):

You have asked me to take a look at this question.

You game does not feel consistent across devices because in your GameViewController you set scene scale mode to .resizeFill. 
In most cases the default .aspectFill setting is the best option.

In regards to the error message you need to give the scene a size in the init method when you are not using the xCode level editor e.g

```
let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: ..., height: ...))
```

There is basically 2 options for size

1) Set the scene size to iPad, which is what I personally do. This is also what Apple uses in DemoBots and what was the default setting in xCode 7. So scene size is either 1024x768 (landscape) or 768x1024 (portrait).

I design my game area with the iPhone in mind, and simply show some more background, usually ground and sky, on iPads. This is what a lot of popular games I like to play do e.g. Modern Combat 5, Limbo, Altos Adventure, Leos Fortune, The Line Zen, Tower Dash.

2) Set the scene size to iPhones and show more background on iPhones and less on iPads e.g. Lumino City.
So scene size would be what xCode 8 uses, either 1334x750 (landscape) or 750x1334 (portrait).

This way your game should feel consistent across all devices. The only thing you might have to do is tweak some UI, like button positioning, between iPad and iPhone.

Hope this helps

Comment: Coming from the linear entertainment mediums of print and motion, I'm inclined to suggest this technique of cropping from a desired ideal is the best approach. It benefits both consistency of experience and (more importantly) the creative experience.

Comment: Yeah definitely agree. I spend over 8 months and 2 games doing it the manual way without any cropping (.resizeFill) before I changed my approach. It was madness to make it a consistent experience on all devices. It also killed my creative experience like you said because I was adjusting stuff half the time for the devices I wasn't testing with instead of improving the actual game itself.

Comment: YES! In a world completely bamboozled by the hype for "cross platform", it's nearly forgotten that the reason we get great experiences (in the first place) is because of creative endeavours by creative folks. Folks were inspired and then persisted through the production problems and realisation frustrations of crafting ideas & conceptions into virtual realities. ALL barriers to realisation and production compromise creativity. I deeply thank you for your very helpful contributions here and on git towards exactly that, making my (and others) life easier with SpriteKit.

Comment: Very true. Thanks for the kind words, just like helping people. I was in the same spot when I started with SpriteKit and Swift and always appreciated people taking the time to answer my simple and probably stupid questions at the time.

Comment: @crashoverride777 you said you design your game area from the center. Does this mean your (0,0) is the center?

Comment: Depends what your anchor point is, I usually use frame.midX/frame.midY. What I mean with design from the centre is that you have to keep the dead zone in mind on the device you are cropping (either iPhone or iPad). So for example if you make a landscape game and use iPad settings (1024x768) you have more frame at the top and bottom on iPads.  So if you put something at frame.maxY or frame.minY you would not see it on iPhones as its cropped. So you would have to say something like frame.maxY - 200 to see it on iPhones. That deadzone is what I mean by designing from center.

Comment: Same applies if you design for iPhones. Say you make landscape game and use iPhone scene size (1334*750), than you would not see stuff at frame.minX or frame.maxX on iPads. So the same logic applies, you would have to keep this deadzone in mind on the device you are cropping.

Comment: @crashoverride777 what happens in the case where I need close to pixel perfection for collision and physics? It seems as if this ranges frame.maxY or frame.minY may cause issues. I have designed my game in such a way that I virtually need pixel perfection to make the game physics function properly

Comment: Your physics and collisions should be much nicer and more consistent in general.

Comment: @crashoverride777 okay, now I am using size 736x414 (iPhone 6+) for my GameScene . The images appear normally when I run the app on an iPhone 6+ but when I run it on an iPhone 5. the edges all round are black

Comment: If you like to use iPhone scene size I would set it to the default xCode 8 setting which is iPhone 6/7 (1334x750 in landscape). You might have to redo your image sizes but its worth the effort. You will normally need at least 3 images that you put in the universal slot in the xCode catalogue or more if you decide to use images specific for each devices. For example a player image put into the asset catalogue might be 50x50 (1x), 100x100 (2x), 150x150(3x). 1x is used for non retina devices and apple TV (if no tv specific slot), 2x is used for iPhone 5/6 and the 3x is used for iPhone 6Plus.

Comment: Interestingly, I have 2x and 3x images in my game. When I removed the 2x images from the asset catelog then then black egdes stopped appearing on my background image on the iPhone 5. Meaning that the 2x image was causing the black edges on my background image. Could you please explain what caused this. I am currently using iPhone images only but very very soon I'll be testing on the iPad and will add iPad images. So I'd like to prepare for them also.

Comment: When you are removing the 2x xCode will use the 1x or 3x image instead. Did you check you haven't made a mistake when you exported the 2x? You usually dont need to add device specific images for everything. I do what apple does in DemoBots, they use universal images for most stuff like background, objects, buttons etc. They only use device specific images for characters, I presume because they have fancy animations so they wanted ultimate quality. In most cases you should be good with the universal image slot and maybe use some device specific ones for stuff you want extra perfect.

Comment: @crashoverride777 My game has got sprites right at the edges top and bottom, it's in the design. How can I work around the iPad cropping iPhone sizes issue?

Comment: @crashoverride777 I'll be more than grateful if you could provide the link to any say Github project that has  implemented iPhone and iPad sizes as you  have explained them

Comment: I dont know about any proper project on gitHub, loads of them are just simple examples or they are old and outdated. There is not much you can do, you have to crop on 1 device, either iPad or iPhone. Depending on how you crop stuff on the edge of the x or y axis will not be shown on either iPad or iPhone. You have to take this into account when designing your game. Or you go the .resizeFill way and stretch your game on iPads and also deal with a million other problems.

Comment: @crashoverride777 I think I get it now. Just a few things that I need to be clarified concerning the 'safe region' when using the iPad size settings. I thought it would benefit a several others so I asked a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529228/how-can-i-find-the-safe-region-for-iphone-size-if-i-am-creating-my-app-using-i

Answer (score 1):

Here is how your code layout should look.  As you can see, I designed the scene to be the size of iPhone 6.  This means on all other phones, the image will scale (but you will still see everything), but will look perfect on the 6.  On the iPad,  the image will get chopped off on the top and the bottom by 12.5% each, due to the iPad being a 3:4 and not 9:16

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    let skView = self.view as? SKView

    if skView?.scene == nil  {
        skView?.showsFPS = true
        skView?.showsNodeCount = true
        skView?.showsPhysics = true
        skView?.ignoresSiblingOrder = false

        //starting the game with the Poster Scene
        let posterScene = PosterScene(size:CGSize(width:375,height:667))
        posterScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        skView?.presentScene(posterScene)
    }

}

override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
    return true
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}
}
```

and

```
class PosterScene: SKScene {

 override init(size:CGSize){
    super.init(size:size)
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.5) //let's put 0,0 at the center of the screen
    let posterImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "poster")
    posterImage.position = CGPoint.zero
    self.addChild(posterImage)

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([  SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0), SKAction.run({ self.changeToMainMenuScene() }) ])

    self.run(sequence)

}

func changeToMainMenuScene  ()  {

    let mainMenuScene = MainMenuScene()
    self.view!.presentScene(mainMenuScene)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm going to have to use the same approach for all my `SKScene`s. I have a bit of an issue with the 25% of my iPad images being cropped out. Is there a way round this?

Comment: well what do you want to happen,  it is impossible to have iphone and ipad to look exactly the same, so I need to know what you plan on doing

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I have been battling with this issue too. My `SKScenes` use `self.size` a lot. Would I have to replace them also with say `UIScreen.main.bounds.size`?

Comment: @Hilarious404 no idea,  I am going to say no

Comment: @Knight0fDragon using static size as you recommended is messing with the physics and positions of the sprites

Comment: @iGetIt, I would need to see that code,  you are obviously doing something else wrong

Comment: You only need to design for 1 size, not 5,  which means you will get consistent results through out all devices.  If your physics is wrong, this means you are not designing for 1 device

Comment: Actually I have 2x and 3x sprite images

Comment: `@2x` and `@3x` is a different issue,  you design your game in 1 size, the higher res gfx gets chosen by iOS on higher res screens,  you never have to worry about it

Comment: so if I have a background image the size of iPhone (320x480)  I make 3 images (320x480,640x960,and 960x1440)  My game will always be 320x480 in size,  but the way the scaler works, on the iPhone 3 it picks the 1x, on iPhone 4 it picks the 2x, and on my hypothetical 6+ iPhone the size of a regular iPhone, it will pick 3x.

Comment: I designed my game generically, often multiplying/dividing `UIScreen.main.bounds` by some factor to arrive at a desired position or using `self.size`. I am testing my game on two devices, everything is okay apart from the sprite speed movement.

Comment: well that is a bad idea,  doing that means you do more work on the CPU,  plus you can easily mess up some math and bug your game

Comment: you can design your game where you can multiply and divide everywhere, or just once (This is what scaling is)  you tell me which is easier lol

Comment: Here is how you should design a game,  You take a piece of paper, and you draw your game.  You then turn on the phones camera.  Hover the phone over your paper. You can zoom in on your phone, zoom out, you can move the phone around to see different parts of the paper, but at no point, do you ever divide the paper up.

Comment: I thought what I am doing is scaling. For example, if set a sprite position as `sprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y:self.size/6)`

Comment: that is not scaling,  that is saying you want the middle of the scene, and 1/6 of the scene.  Well you now know scene size, so you do not have to do that math at runtime anymore, you can do it at build time.  Which makes it a lot easier to understand your code

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. In other words, I have to use one dimension throughout my game, whether 375x667 (iPhone6) or 414x736 (iPhone 6+) and it will scale based on the device I am running on. Right? But when I used `PosterScene(size:CGSize(width:375,height:667))` as above, the image was zoomed in.

Comment: IGetIt,  that is because I cannot predict what device you are basing your game on,  IPhone 6 size is the most popular device size , so you want to give that best quality

Comment: Okay, lets say I am using the iPhone 6. You also changed the anchor point. That makes (0,0)  the center. I guess that changes everything within `SKScene`

Comment: @iGetIt, yes it does,  the reason why is because it makes it a lot easier when dealing with different aspect ratios, since you need to deal with cropping on both sides of the screen

Comment: Your point @Knight0fDragon, about scaling etc, probably all very good points. But your way of claiming it, and the need for it, in abrupt, curt, and sometimes VERY abrupt and absolute ways is the opposite of descriptive and explanatory.

Comment: I'm not at all surprised @iGetIt is having trouble getting it. I'm sure anyone that doesn't know what you're talking about would have trouble understanding your points, too.

Comment: this causes an error of " doesn't match any available overloads": `override init(size:CGSize){super.init(size)`

Comment: it should be, from the looks of what worked for me: `super.init(size: size)` which is an incredible indication of your typing speed. You must type faster than the error checker.

Comment: @Confused, I keep telling you this, I am not holding peoples hands, I am going to let iGetIt struggle, I am going to beat him down till he gets it, he is going to get his AHA I finally understand it moment, and he is going to appreciate it.  This is why I am very patient and persistent with my comments.  Some of the best teachers I have ever had was because they made me struggle, but they never gave up on me, and I apply that same philosophy to everyone I talk to.  Don't like it, tough, it is a cut throat world out here, and when you are doing it for a living, they will not hold your hands.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I've just read through this post and the linked one and all the comments. Personally, I prefer using iGetIt's original way of handling positions and sizes, and from the look of things he's going to have to make  a world of changes implement your suggestion. I believe there should be a simpler way for him to get consistent sprite movement. Either by finding a factor to multiply the sprite speed based on the screen dimensions or something similar. Thats my opinion.

Comment: @chronos, that is fine for you to think that. The changes needed in his code will be well worth it though, for 2 reasons alone. 1) Less likely to have mathematical errors causing bugs, 2) Saves on CPU usage, which allows you to use that time for fancier processes. A minor reason, when using SKAction, you do not have to multiply time duration when doing things over a fixed period of time.

Comment: @chronos, here is an example of saving time.  Moving 100 sprites: `for i in 0..<100 { sprite[i].run(SKAction.move(by: CGPointMake(scene.size.width/10,0)))}` vs `for i in 0..<100 { sprite[i].run(SKAction.move(by: CGPointMake(37.5,0)))}` Now for areas where bugs may happen,  issues like scaling (let's say width is INT).  `sprite.scale = width/375 * 2`,  Uh Oh, we just did integer division, we needed floating point, now our scale is off.  My method `sprite.scale = 2`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon changing the anchor point makes the (0, 0) the center, a bit like the Unity system. I wouldn't like to change that. Also how can I prevent the image from zooming.

Comment: @chronos, also, you now have to worry about aspect ratios across different devices, When a sprite moves diagonally, how does it look on the different device.  It may look great on an ipad,  but look terrible on an iphone because your sprite is moving more to the up, then to the right.  There are so many things to consider it is crazy, that is what is so fascinating about game development, so many problems to solve.

Comment: @iGetIt, yes, like Unity.  We are taught in geometry that the origin is naturally in the center.  It makes things a lot easier to understand.  Let's say you want to rotate the scene to add a tornado effect.  on all of your SKNodes, you would just apply an angle.  But on the SKScene, you need to translate half screen width, half screen height, rotate, then translate back

Comment: @iGetIt, if you want to add a mirror effect,  you could just add a node at the negative x or y position, instead of having to do translates all over the place.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon that is a very steep curve for me. A lot of the logic and complex issues have been solved using the usual bottom left as (0,0). How can I combine using the the bottom left as anchor and the iPhone 6 size?

Comment: @iGetIt, you do not have to change the anchor point if you do not want to,  if you already have it designed to bottom left, just take it out.  It affects nothing for you.  For future people who may come across this and are getting started, they may find it a lot more useful.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon That said, how can I prevent the image from zooming?

Comment: what do you mean zooming?  This is why in the beginning I asked what are you trying to accomplish across devices, without knowing this, I cant help you

Comment: can you provide me with 5 pictures,  what you expect the game to look like on [iPhone 5,5S,Se], [Iphone 6,6s,7], [iphone 6+,6s+,7+], iPad, and iPad Pro

Comment: The `PosterScene` sets a background image. This image seems to be zoomed in when I use the `PosterScene(size: CGSize(width:375,height:667))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127733/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-igetit).

Comment: @Knight0fDragon  I think I now get what you were explaining yesterday. Just a few things that I need to be clarified concerning the 'safe region' when using the iPad size settings. I thought it would benefit a several others so I asked a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529228/how-can-i-find-the-safe-region-for-iphone-size-if-i-am-creating-my-app-using-i?noredirect=1#comment68300163_40529228

Comment: @Knight0fDragon please can we chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127733/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-igetit